# How to open InAppBrowser in a modal with Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, inappbrowser

I have InAppBrowser installed in my project, I can open a window with

```
window.open('https://www.google.com/');
```

When I execute that a window slides from the bottom covering the screen and loads the requested page.

I want that behavior, but instead of completely taking over the screen I want it to have 80-90% of the screen height, leaving space at the top to show my app header.

Is there a way to do that? Like open a webpage in a modal or a config to change the browser height?

Any other plugin that can do that and also open a browser without leaving the app would also be fine. I guess iframes are not an option because I need to open Twitter, Youtube, Facebook, Instagram and apparently they don't allow iframes

[image: browser]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this fork of in-app-browser?  https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser